# Postman Post not working despite the API working everywhere else

Tags: sql, post, swagger, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API project with this post endpoint:

```
   [HttpPost("post")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Player>> PostPlayer(Player player)
        {
            _context.Players.Add(player);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetPlayer", new { id = player.Id }, player);
        }
```

I can make a post request in Swagger to that endpoint with this JSON payload:

```
{
  "handle": "Cole",
  "role": "Fixer",
  "avatar": "null"
}
```

At this address: `https://localhost:44326/api/Players/post`.

And it successfully creates a new Player.

However, in Postman using the same address and same JSON payload for the body I get this:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
    "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "status": 415,
    "traceId": "00-36aa0c0b65a981479a1bb99d32400eff-77eb26e1d840de4d-00"
}
```

What does this even mean? Why doesn't this post method work in Postman? All of my Get endpoints work fine in Postman, just not this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your request body is JSON, you need to make sure that you have selected the correct header and the correct type of request in body tab of Postman.

- Set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` (Add it if it is not there).
- Go to *Body* tab of Postman, select the *raw* radio button, and then select *JSON* from the dropdown next to radio buttons.

If the above steps don't work then the best way is to compare the working request (from Swagger) to the Postman request. Here is how you can do that:

- Open swagger page in the Google Chrome browser, then open Developer Tools (right click in Chrome on the Swagger page, then click *Inspect*). It will open Developer Tools.
- Go to the *Network* tab of the Developer Tools, select *Fetch/XHR filter*.
- Then make the request to your API by clicking the *Try now* button of Swagger.
- You will see the API call in the details in the *Network* tab; you can then inspect what headers your web application is sending to your API. Inspect what value it is passing for the `Content-Type` header.

Once you have a working request traced in the *Network* tab, it should be easy to figure out how your Postman request looks different from the Swagger request.